# Is parameter expansion in test expression possible?

Tags: bash, command-substitution, test, arithmetic

When I try the following expression in `bash` I get a strange error message:

```
[: -lt: unary operator expected
```

First the function definition

```
some_func () {
  (( 3 + 5 ))
}
```

And the expression

```
[ $(some_func) -lt 10 ] && true
```

I guess the problem is mixing operators like `-lt` with command substitution and/or arithmetic expansion?

The exit code `$?` is 2 and the message is *`an unary op was expected`*.

Comment: When asking about an error message, please always include the actual error.

Answer (score 6):

**It should be**

```
some_func() {
  echo "$(( 3 + 5 ))"
}
[ "$(some_func)" -lt 10 ]
```

---

**Why it failed**

`$(some_func)` expands to the **output** of the function* (minus its trailing newline), which however outputs nothing. Therefore, the test becomes

```
[ -lt 10 ]
```

In its most basic forms, [the `[` test accepts 1 to 3 parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions). Since above there are 2 parameters, Bash expects the 1st one to be an unary operator. `-lt` is binary, hence the error message.

Had you [quoted the expansion as appropriate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) with

```
[ "$(some_func)" -lt 10 ]
```

The error would be "integer expression expected" because the test would have the empty string:

```
[ "" -lt 10 ]
```

And, unless under [non-trivial circumstances](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/652472/is-parameter-expansion-in-test-expression-possible#comment1225058_652476), `&& true` is redundant.

<sup>*Since the expansion is unquoted, the output also undergoes [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) and [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html). These shouldn't play a part in the present example, though as long as `$IFS` has not been changed from its default value.</sup>

Comment: `&& true` would not be redundant if the `errexit` option has been enabled or a `trap` on `ERR` has been set.

Answer (score 4):

`$(cmd)` gets the *standard output* of `cmd`¹, so for that to expand to the result, you need `cmd` to *output* it:

```
some_func() {
  echo "$(( 3 + 5 ))"
}
[ "$(some_func)" -lt 10 ]
```

as others have already said. However, that means `some_func` is run in a subshell environment, so any modification to variables or anything else will be lost afterwards.

For instance, there's no point doing:

```
counter=0
incr() { echo "$((++counter))"; }
while [ "$(incr)" -le 10 ]...
```

as `$(incr)` will always expand to 1 (as `counter` will only be incremented in the subshell).

For a function to return a numerical result via an *arithmetic evaluation*, you'd need a shell with support for *math functions* like `ksh93` or `zsh`. `bash` won't do.

In `zsh`:

```
counter=0
incr() (( ++counter ))
functions -M incr

while (( incr() <= 10 )); do
  print $counter
done
```

In `ksh93`:

```
function .sh.math.incr i {
  # ksh93 functions must take at least one argument
  (( .sh.value = (counter += i) ))
}
while (( incr(1) <= 10 )); do
  print "$counter"
done
```

Another alternative in ksh93 or recent versions of mksh is to use forms of command substitution that don't introduce subshells:

```
counter=0
function incr { print "$(( ++counter ))"; }
while [ "${ incr; }" -le 10 ]; do
  print "$counter"
done
```

Or in `mksh`:

```
counter=0
incr() (( REPLY = ++counter ))
while [ "${| incr; }" -le 10 ]; do
  print "$counter"
done
```

In any POSIX shell including `bash`, you can always return the value in a predefined variable (`$REPLY` is commonly used for that):

```
counter=0
incr() { REPLY=$(( counter += 1 )); }
while incr; [ "$REPLY" -le 10 ]; do
  echo "$counter"
done
```

You'll find more details at [this answer to another Q&A about mksh's valsub feature](/a/611364)

---

<sup>¹ stripped of its trailing newline characters, and in the case of `bash` of its NUL characters, and here because you forgot the quotes, subject to split+glob</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Command substitution *captures the output* of a command or function. That function has no output.

The `$?` variable holds the *return code* of the function.

Either do this:

```bsh
some_func
(( $? < 10 )) && echo yes
```

or change the function to:

```bsh
some_func() {
    echo $(( 3 + 5 ))
}

[[ $(some_func) -lt 10 ]] && echo yes
```

---

Notice how I'm using `[[...]]` instead of `[...]`? The double bracket conditional is more forgiving about empty values.

Comment: Ok, that test was falsey. I tried to test why the interpreter complains about my bash script where the command substituted function actually *does* `echo` something and I get the same error message `too many arguments`. The line is `if [ $(lookahead 1) = "-" ]; then...` and the function is `lookahead () { if [[ $(($current_char_index + $1)) -lt ${#current_char} ]]; then echo "${current_token:$current_char_index:$1}"; else parsing_error! "lookahead goes over end of current token"; fi; }` Hope I set the semicolons correct to make it a one liner.

Comment: @vonspotz please be sure to add any relevant information into the original question rather than answering in comments.

Comment: I thought my example would be representative enough to avoid posting the code from the script. Obviously it wasn't. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: Too many unknowns in that code: what does `parsing_error!` do? Assuming it prints a value to stdout, then `[ $(lookahead 1) = "-" ]` becomes `[ lookahead goes over end of current token = "-" ]` and that's indeed too many arguments. It's very important to use proper quoting within `[...]`

Comment: Note that `[` is a synonym for the `test` command. At an interactive bash prompt, enter `help test` and see that "The behavior of test depends on the number of arguments."

Comment: I wouldn't advertise `[[ $(cmd) -lt 10 ]]` here as that's a command injection vulnerability as the output of `cmd` is interpreted as an arithmetic expression. `[ "$(cmd)" -lt 10 ]` doesn't have the problem, but of course you mustn't forget the quotes!